# Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint MySQL Error

Tags: c#, mysql

Im making an Order table in which paintings_id and customer_id act as foreign keys and they correspond to customers_id and painting_id which act as primary keys in their respective tables. They have the same datatype that is Int. I have searched for this error but cannot find any possible solution.

```
use artgallery;
CREATE TABLE item_order(
order_id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL auto_increment,
customer_id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
paintings_id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,

primary key(order_id),
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customers_id),
FOREIGN KEY(paintings_id) references pantings(painting_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cut and pasted your create table statement as-is...and it worked fine.  Your error must be generated from something other than mysql....which brings me to another point...what's the error?
....nevermind...I see your error in the subject field.....not sure...as I said it worked fine on MySQL version 5.1.

Comment: Done. It was a Spelling mistake xD

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your foreign key reference columns have the same definition as the columns in your other tables.

For example, you are adding a foreign key with this column as the reference:

customer_id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL

Which means 'customers_id' in your 'customers' table must be:

customers_id INT NOT NULL (possibly AUTO_INCREMENT)

If you define one as 'UNSIGNED' and/or 'NULL' / 'NOT NULL', the referenced column must also have those attributes. See [Using Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).